# Django rest framework pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Django and am trying to make use of view sets and pagination. I've got the following classes, as per the documentation:

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
    page_size_query_param = 'ps'
    max_page_size = 1000

class SequenceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SequenceSerializer
    queryset = Sequence.objects.all()
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

Routing is set up so that `/sequences` routes to the view set, and that all works great. Furthermore either of these works great:

```
/sequences?page=4
/sequences?ps=3
```

However, combining the two parameters seems not to work. If I do, the `ps` parameter is ignored. I have scoured the web for a bug report or indication of what I might be doing incorrectly to no avail. Am I missing something crucial? Am I supposed to be able to specify both the page size and the page simultaneously?

For reference, I'm using Django 1.10.3, and DRF 3.5.3.

Comment: Are you combining them correctly? As in: `/sequences?page=4&ps=3` or `/sequences?ps=3&page=4`

Comment: Yep - just as you showed (I tried both orderings, which obviously shouldn't matter..) What happens is the page parameter is respected but not the ps parameter. Since the default page size set up is 10, in the case you gave I get a page of 10 results that starts at record 31. I've also tried using other names for the page size param. Oddly, if I don't specify the page, then the ps parameter works OK.  There isn't any other funny business going on in the code either..from your point of view, it should be permissible to specify both simultaneously, right?